# How to add a .css style to an app with Shiny and Flexdashboard?

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am developing an application in Shiny with Flexdashboard which will be hosted on a server and I am trying to place a style.css to the dashboard, which does not work when using Shiny.

I have not found any answers, does anyone know what could be happening?

I leave some code and images as examples, and I remain attentive to your comments.

YAML header without Shiny:

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    css: estilo2.css
---
```

Output without Shiny:

[image: WO_Shiny]

YAML header with Shiny:

```
---
title: "Title"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    css: estilo2.css
---
```

Output with Shiny

[image: W_Shiny]

I also tried placing the .css file in a www/estilo2.css folder, but it doesn't work.

```
---
title: "Title"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    css: www/estilo2.css
---
```

Comment: Hi @Wolkuz, welcome to SO, about css you can read this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905726/bootswatch-theme-in-shiny-flexdashboard-r] where I had a similar problem accessing CSS.

Comment: Hi @Wolkuz did you find a fix to this, as I'm facing this same issue now